# Ada static compilation

Tags: windows, compilation, static, ada, gnat

I have compiled a [simple Ada application](http://www.adapower.com/adapower1/os/hello.html) which uses the [Win32Ada](https://github.com/AdaCore/win32ada) library.

I'm compiling the application on Windows using:

`gnatmake C:\GNAT\2020\bin\src\main.adb -I"C:\GNAT\2020\lib\win32ada" -largs -lwin32ada`.

The application works as expected on the compilation machine and when executing `main.exe` a `MessageBox` is executed.

However, when attempting to execute the application on another Windows system which doesn't have the `Ada` libraries installed, I received an error:

[image: The code execution cannot processed because libwin32ada.dll was not found]

Does `Ada` support static compilation?

Can I compile the application so `main.exe` can execute on any Windows host without needing to bundle `DLL`'s?

I couldn't find an answer in the `gnatmake --help` (but I'm also new to `Ada`).

Comment: why not install the libraries on the second machine? Linking a Windows GUI program statically is likely to produce a rather large executable.

Comment: I want to interface with the Windows API, not necessarily create a GUI. MessageBox was just a PoC of interfacing with the API.

Answer (score 1):

The default linking mode is static on Windows. So, normally, you don't need to add any option. If you need to force it, use the `-bargs -static` gnatmake binder option or add

```
 package Binder is
    for Default_Switches ("ada") use ("-static");
 end Binder;
```

to your .gpr project file.

Comment: I forced the `-bargs -static` option, however I still see the same error for the lacking DLL when executing on another host.

Comment: Some configuration in this version of the win32ada library seems to require the DLL.

Comment: Side note: if you want to program user interfaces, as your Message Box example seems to suggest, you can use GWindows which is standalone and DLL-less (see https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnavi/ or https://github.com/zertovitch/gwindows )

Comment: I'm trying this on Ubuntu and this just results in a dynamically-linked application. How would this work on Linux?

Comment: Try with `-static` on both gpr packages: Linker *and* Binder.

Answer (score 0):

> Does Ada support static compilation?

Yes, it's the default mode.

> Can I compile the application so main.exe can execute on any Windows host without needing to bundle DLL's?

You should be able to, but I haven't used the win32ada library much; I would be surprised if you couldn't do something like Deplhi where the executable interfaces with the Win32 API "directly", albeit with the abstraction of the VCL.

I think the item you want to flag is in the Linker, not Binder. (Though you might need both.) The best place to check for the nitty-gritty of arguments for GNAT is [the documentation](https://docs.adacore.com/gnat_ugn-docs/html/gnat_ugn/gnat_ugn/building_executable_programs_with_gnat.html), simply because there's a huge number of arguments which are essentially non-intuitive in their naming or usage.

`--unchecked-shared-lib-imports` might be of interest; checking out the win32ada project file (especially any scenario variables) might give you the ability to switch it to a static library. In the worst case, if you add `For library_kind use "static";` to the Win32Ada library, you should be able to build it statically yourself.